# How to reset a timer every minute if there is no query to the database?

Tags: php, timer, refresh, listener

I have a basic server in PHP and from the mobile device I send data and save the server every 1 minute.

But when ever my mobile phone loses the connection, I would like to set a counter on the server and if the mobile does not insert anything the database longer than 2 min. I would like to call a function in the server saying that your mobile lost connection. Every time the mobile phone sends the data to the server, timer will be reset.

I am not familiar to PHP but I searched and couldn't find any similar things. I am sure there must be an easy way of doing it. setting a listener or creating a count down timer.

Comment: Sounds like you can't do this purely with a web server. Do you have access to cron jobs? Or you can ssh in to your account?

Comment: No I dont. I just use basic php files that saves data into database and read data from the database. So there is no such controller that can listen. When I think logic it sounds easy. when ever I call the update.php file, inside the php file I will have a variable as a counter every time this file is called the number will be reset. and basically this varialble will be countdown with the time. Im not sure it might sound so odd to you. I have no idea about the php files. So there is no way to have a basic counter and keep resetting it with every request?

Comment: no there isn't. php files served from a web server can't operate outside the confines of the requests. so there is no process that can "count down". this would have to be a background service.

Comment: Thats the question how can I do that :)

Comment: My point is that you *can't* do that with just a php server.

Comment: You need access to either cron jobs or a shell script that you can run as a daemon.

Comment: I have no idea about them. and dont know how they work. But thank you I will be reading about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it worked. What I learned is that the server cant do anything if there is no request:) So I created a timestamp field in the database and update the current time with the request. Of course before updating the field gets it and compare it with the current time and see when was the last request. and find out the time difference. if the time difference bigger than 2 min change the position. I hope this helps other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a timer in your PHP code as it runs only when a client requests a page.

As you doesn't have an access to CRON jobs, you can't do it from CLI side either.

However, some webservices allow you to periodically call a page of your choice, so you can `save()` on every http://something/save.php call. Take a look at http://www.google.fr/search?ie=UTF-8&q=online+cron for more informations.

Note that if someone get the `save()` url, he can easily overload your server. Try to secure it as most as possible, maybe with a user/password combination passed as parameters.